# Only one attachInterrupt works at a time

Tags: microcontroller, msp430, launchpad, energia

I am using the MSP430f5529 launchpad and coding in Energia.

The goal is to make a program that can detect whether the onboard pushbutton is up or down (as part of an eventual Morse code decoder), which I planned to implement using two `attachInterrupt`s.

If I use one, for example `attachInterrupt(BUTTON, buttonPress, FALLING)`, it works fine and the button press is detected. If I use `attachInterrupt(BUTTON, buttonRelease, RISING)`, the button release is detected.

However, if I have both`attachInterrupts` in the same program, only one of them works; based on trial and error, it seems whichever interrupt was declared last takes precedence.

In the below code, for example, only `buttonPress` fires. If I swap the order of my `attachInterrupt`s, only `buttonRelease` will fire.

```
#define BUTTON PUSH2

volatile int buttonDown = 987; // set to an arbitrary value so I can tell if the functions changed it at all

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Test code for buttons");

  // Enable internal pullup
  pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT_PULLUP);
  // attaching release before press
  attachInterrupt(BUTTON, buttonRelease, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(BUTTON, buttonPress, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("buttonDown: ");
  Serial.println(buttonDown);
}

void buttonPress() {
  buttonDown = 1;
}

void buttonRelease() {
  buttonDown = 0;
}
```

How can I make both `buttonRelease` and `buttonPress` work at the correct times? I tried to just check if the button state changed using a single interrupt (that detected CHANGE, not just RISING or FALLING), but that seemed to lead to even more problems down the road, since the hardware would sometimes register a change in the middle of running the code needed to process what to do with that change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the pins that support pin change interrupts (P1, P2), each pin has a flag that controls which edge the interrupt is triggered on. This means that the pin cannot trigger an interrupt for a rising edge AND a falling edge like you want. See [Page 308](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau445g/slau445g.pdf)